# Load jquery opendialog asynchronously with ruby on rails using haml

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I'm working on a rails web app. In one of my views (at index.html.haml) I have a jquery opendialog where I list a few things.
My problem is I don't want to load this when the index page is loaded but at the openclick event.
I'll provide some of the code. I am still new to rails, haml and jquery so any help will be welcomed, thanks in advance.

Regards.

```
#...stuff

#dialog creation and loading
.dialog{:id => "codes_#{stuff.id}", :title => t_s(:index, resource_class.to_s.downcase)}
  #dialog: haml code with the list loading that is done when the main page is loaded instead on being called at the onclick

#link that opens the dialog
= link_to t_s(:show, resource_class.to_s.downcase), '#', :onclick => "openDialog(#{stuff.id})", :title => t_s(:show, resource_class.to_s.downcase)+ " " +t_s(:index, resource_class.to_s.downcase)

#...stuff
```

this is some of the generated js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".dialog").dialog({ width: 600, height: 400, autoOpen: false, modal: true, show: "blind", hide: "explode"
 });
}); 
function openDialog(id){ 
$("#codes_"+id).dialog( "open" ); return false; 
}
```

Regards

Comment: Can you share your javascript as well?

Comment: the problem is you're opening the dialog on `document.ready` which is why your dialog loads when the document becomes ready.  You want to move that inside that the function `openDialog`.  Also I would have added the JS code editing the post for better readability.

Comment: By doing that the dialog now shows up when I load the page, instead of being hidden until I click the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already fixed it myself, I'll add the explanation here: 
1)removed the haml and only left de div, put the haml in a partial 
2)added an action in the controller: def dialog stuff = Stuff.find(params[:stuff_id]) render :partial => "partial_name",:locals => { :stuff => stuff }, :layout => false end

3)in the javascript: $("#div_id").empty();

$.ajax({ type: 'GET', url: 'url of the action in this case dialog', cache: false, data: { stuff_id: stuff_id }, success: function(html){ $("#div_id"+stuff_id).append(html); } });

Hope this can help someone else.

Regards